# Can I initiate transaction and allow user to set `value` in wallet?

Tags: transactions, wallets, user-defined-value-types

I want a button that initiates a transaction to a given address and then lets the user decide the `value` in their wallet before sending the transaction. If I include no value, then the transaction is sent with a zero value and there is no wallet option to change that.

[The docs](https://docs.web3js.org/api/web3-eth/function/sendTransaction/) don't indicate if setting the value is possible, so I thought I'd ask just in case there is a way, or perhaps it's on the road map.

Comment: Why not let the user decide the value in the UI then just confirm it in the wallet?

Comment: @ruby_newbie Yes, that's an option. In this case I'm extending an existing UI – adding value options would require a more significant overhall, so leaving it to the wallet would be preferable.